# Is a function invertible, multidimensional

Tags: calculus

I have learned in Linear algebra that a linear map is invertible if n=m
But what if the map is not linear. I have researched this the whole day but to no end.

I am trying to answer a question where i am asked to show whether  a function is invertible at two specific points.

I have not found a lot of info on it, of course it has to go from R^n to R^m with n=m.

The only think i can think of is that i know that the derivative of the inverse equals 1 devided by the derivative of the original function.

Is it that i can show that if i can invert the Jacobi Matrix (at a specific point) of a function (that is that the determinant>0) then there exists an inverse function?

Here is the function

[image]

If i calculated the Jacobi Matrices at the points (1,0) and (2,1) correctly then both determinants would be positive. Does this mean the function is invertible at this two points?

Is there any good site, or video or book which does explain this clearly for someone who does not major in maths. I don’t really get how an inverse of a multidimensional function would look like, and what it means to invert a function in a single point.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You often can only guarantee a local inverse; this is the content of the inverse function theorem. I'll state this theorem for you precisely, then say what it means after:

Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be open and $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous differentiable. Suppose that $x_0\in E$ is such that $Df(x_0):\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is invertible. Then, there exist open sets $U$ in $E$ containing $x_0$ and $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing $f(x_0)$ such that $f$ is a diffeomorphism from $U$ to $V$.

Since you might not want this precision (as your post seems to indicate), let me say what this means. If our function is continuously differentiable and there exists point $x_0$ where the Jacobian is invertible, then we can invert our function near $x_0$, and our local inverse is continuously differentiable, as well. Note that this gives the existence of the local inverse; it doesn't tell us how to find it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I would love to understand the precise definition, but most of the time my math is not good enough. So the jacobian is invertible if the determinant is greater 0? And when is a function continuously differentiable, the jacobian exists and every partial derivative is continuous?

Comment: If you'd like to strengthen your formal math and work up to a statement like this, you might like to check out Tao's "Analysis I" and "Analysis II" (this theorem is covered about 2/3 of the way through the second book).